# How to get data from client side(android) to server side(ROR) in create action(post method)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, post

I am sending an data from client side to server side,from server side it has to fetch that data what i am sending from client side.

for that we have to use post method in def create action.

Serversudecide(ROR)

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json, :xml

  before_filter :load

  def load
    if signed_in?
      @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      @my_post = current_user.posts.new
    end
    @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
    @post = Post.new
  end


  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_with(@posts) do |format|
      format.json { render json: @post_names = {:post => @posts.as_json(:only=> :content)} }
    end
  end 

  def show
    if signed_in?
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      current_user.vote_for(@post)
    else
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    Guest.find(1).vote_for(@post)
    end
    @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)  
    @guest = Guest.new
    @user = User.new
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
  end

  def create 
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
     respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created }

    else 
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

    end
    @guest = Guest.new
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
 end
  end

  def my_prayer_create     
      @my_post = current_user.posts.new(params[:post])
      @post = Post.new(params[:post])
      @guest = Guest.new
      @user = User.new
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      if @my_post.save
        flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully created."
        @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      else 
        flash[:notice] = "Error"
        @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      end
  end

  def edit
    if signed_in?    
    @my_post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    else
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

  def update
    if signed_in? 
      @my_post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
      if @my_post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully updated."
        @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      end
    else  
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if signed_in? 
      @my_post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      @guest = Guest.new
      @my_post.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully destroyed."
      @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
    end
  end
```

clientside code also i mention here.

```
public class HomeLayoutActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        private EditText value;
        private Button btn;
        private ProgressBar pb;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
            value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_layout, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                    // out of range
                    Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());  
                }


        } 

        private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postData(params[0]);
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
                pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }

            public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://dry-brushlands-3645.herokuapp.com/posts");

                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", valueIWantToSend));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    //httppost.addHeader("Authorization","Basic "+authorization);
                    //httppost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The request made from the client side is somewhat similar to this if I'm right:

- The `post` data from your client side is of the form: `&content=valueIWantToSend`
- In the ROR application, in the `def create` method, `params[:content]` will equal `valueIWantToSend`.

Either change `params[:post]` to `params[:content]` on the server-side or change `content` to `post` on the client-side (Inside the `try` block)

Comment: actually in server side i have table having title and content,from that content value only i want to send,that why i am mention as content in android,what ever i am typing it has to go to the content column

Comment: Updated the answer. Change the `params[:post]` to `params[:content]` in the RoR application.

Comment: Stop calling me dude. And it's `params[:content]` not params:content.

Comment: There is a visible mismatch between the server-side code and the client-side code. May be you're getting confused because of the documentation language on Android's and Rails' websites. Also, how did you generate the server-side code?